# Qt won't recognize headers from sub directory /Include

Tags: c++, qt

Environment

I am on Windows 7 64bit
Qt Creator 3.4.2 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.5.0 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)

Goal

I am using a 3rd party library. I need to #include  the library files like that since that is how the library files include their dependencies.

What I have tried

in myFunction.h (in same directory as .pro file)

```
#include <lib_header.h>
...
```

in .pro file

```
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/Debug/" -llib_name
SUBDIRS += "$$PWD/Include"
DEPENDPATH += "$$PWD/Include"
INCLUDEPATH += "$$PWD/Include"
DEPENDPATH += "C:/Users/Steves Laptop/UX3D/Include"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Users/Steves Laptop/UX3D/Include"
VPATH += "$$PWD/Include"
VPATH += "C:/Users/Steves Laptop/UX3D/Include"
...
```

lib_header.h is in /Include

Results

I get tool tip when hovering over the #include  line of the exact location of the file. On compile it says it can't be found. I expect this is a newbie mistake but have spent 3 hrs wasted so far. If in my files I do it like this `#include <Include/lib_header.h>` it works. I need a way to reference them directly though in order for the rest of the library to work.

Even if someone could provide a link or reference source file that documents Qt's implementation of the #include <> tag that would be sufficient.

Comment: Try changing your includepath to INCLUDEPATH += "./Include"

Comment: also, I guess you should avoid paths containing spaces